# Is it possible to correctly escape arbitrary script tag contents?

Tags: html, escaping

Question about ETAGO - end-tag open: Given a string, is it possible to safely escape it in a generic way for insertion into a sprintf style template like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>tag demo</title>
    <script type="%s">
%s
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I've seen [descriptions](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/etago) that show how to escape various specific strings, but nothing generic.

Is it really true that such escaping is impossible in a generic way?

Here are some edge cases:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>tag demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var endtag = "</a>";
        // OK, this is weird - but valid!
        var lessthan = 42 < /script/;
        console.log (endtag, lessthan, '<'.match(/</));
        // The next two lines are weird - and cause invalid HTML
        // </script>
        var lessthan2 = 42 </script/;
        // Is this still being run?
        console.log ("still here");
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This is not valid HTML since the `</script` sequence is found inside the script tag's "weird" lines. If I move the inner HTML from the script tag to an external .js file, `still here` gets logged to the console, and I believe it to be valid javascript, just not valid HTML when inside a script tag. Is there some safe generic way to escape a javascript (or css? or `type="foo/bar"`?) string for insertion into a script tag?

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't seem possible. The [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) says (modulo hacks to make it appear in markdown here):

> 4.12.1.3 Restrictions for contents of script elements
>
> The easiest and safest way to avoid the rather strange restrictions described in this section is to always escape "<!--" as "<\!--", "< script" as "<\script", and "< /script" as "<\/script" when these sequences appear in literals in scripts (e.g. in strings, regular expressions, or comments), and to avoid writing code that uses such constructs in expressions. Doing so avoids the pitfalls that the restrictions in this section are prone to triggering: namely, that, for historical reasons, parsing of script blocks in HTML is a strange and exotic practice that acts unintuitively in the face of these sequences.

And a little further down:

> It is possible for these sequences to naturally occur in script expressions, as in the following examples:

```
if (x<!--y) { ... }
if ( player<script ) { ... }
```

> In such cases the characters cannot be escaped, but the expressions can be rewritten so that the sequences don't occur, as in:
> <language-specific rewrites>

So according to the spec, it isn't possible, apparently.

I'm quite surprised. But that does occur frequently... ;-)